# How to create a nuget package (core) with some html, and use this html files, when I run in a dotnet CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a package using "dotnet pack", and I have some html files, to use like a template.

I already generated some packages and opened, the html files are there, in a content folder:

├───content:  template.html
├───lib: netcoreapp2.0, scaff.dll, scaff.runtimeconfig.json

My question is: how can I access those html files when a I run a dotnet CLI command like "dotnet scaff" from the project where I installed the package?
What path I must use? I tried content/template.html and only template.html, but it gave an exception.

Here are the content configuration in my csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="content\**\*" PackagePath="%(Identity)" />
</ItemGroup>
```